# Cannot exit from AngularJS view

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

We have ASP.NET application that contains menu bar (derived from UserControl) on top and several standard content pages below. But, there's one page below that is not standard content page. It's HTML page that is used as view for AngularJS controller. There's an "exit" option on menu and when you click it, it works for all standard content pages, but not for AngularJS view. When you are on AngularJS view and click "exit", nothing happens. I need to exit as well when I click "exit" when I'm on AngularJS view.

The code looks as following:

1) The part of menu bar:

```
<td width="65" align="center" class="mainMenu" onmouseover=" this.style.background = '#F5F6AF'; " onmouseout=" this.style.background = '#E8E8E8'; ">
    <site:secureLink ID="CashdeskReport" RunAt="Server" CssClass="MainMenu" Name="report" Allow="wizard,admin,kassaThermo,kassa,kassaPechat,kassaPechatSpec,kassaPechatExt,kassaExpress,kassaManager" URL="../Admin/Admin_Report.aspx" />
</td>
<td width="65" align="center" class="mainMenu" onmouseover=" this.style.background = '#F5F6AF'; " onmouseout=" this.style.background = '#E8E8E8'; ">
    <a runat="server" ID="exit" CausesValidation="False">exit</a>
</td>
```

2) The code for exit:

```
private void exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuthManager.GetCurrent().LogOut();
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/Admin.aspx");
}
```

3) HTML page:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="Default_New.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="Concert.Default_New" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="site" TagName="header" Src="includes/Header.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="site" TagName="head" Src="includes/Head.ascx" %>

<!doctype html>

<html id="ng-app" ng-app="cashdeskActionSearchApp">
    <head>
        <site:head id="Head" runat="Server" />        
        <link href="bootstrap/v3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="css/actions.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="css/new_search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="includes/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/toastr.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        <script src="Scripts/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/i18n/moment.ru.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        <script src="bootstrap/v3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        <script src="angular/1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular/1.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <%--<script src="angular/angular-cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>--%>
        <script src="angular/ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/i18n/angular-locale_ru.js"></script>
        <script src="/Admin/js/services.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="/Admin/js/directives.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/CashdeskActionSearchApp.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#333333" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <%--<site:secureChecker ID="CheckRights" runat="Server" Allow="wizard,admin,buhgalter" />--%>
        <site:header id="HeaderInclude" runat="server"/>

        <!--<h2 style="padding-left: 10px;">Поиск мероприятий</h2>-->
        <div>
            <div ng-view class="container-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

4) How it looks like in browser's debugger (Script section):

```
<!doctype html>

<html id="ng-app" ng-app="cashdeskActionSearchApp">
    <head>

<title></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="title" content="">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days">
<meta name="home_url" content="http://www.concert.ru">
<meta name="robots" content="index,all">
<meta name="copyright" content="http://www.concert.ru">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru">
<link href=includes/Style.css type=text/css rel=stylesheet>

        <link href="bootstrap/v3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="css/actions.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="css/new_search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="includes/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/toastr.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        <script src="Scripts/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/i18n/moment.ru.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        <script src="bootstrap/v3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        <script src="angular/1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular/1.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        <script src="angular/ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/i18n/angular-locale_ru.js"></script>
        <script src="/Admin/js/services.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="/Admin/js/directives.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/CashdeskActionSearchApp.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#333333" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">



<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="src.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function MoveMonth(dest) {
        document.forms[0].MoveMonthDest.value = dest;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>

<table width="99%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>

    </tr>
</table>
<br/>






<table width="99%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
    <tr>
        <td width="6"><img src="../img/l.gif" width="6" height="28"></td>
        <td width="65" align="center" class="mainMenu" onmouseover=" this.style.background = &#39;#F5F6AF&#39;; " onmouseout=" this.style.background = &#39;#E8E8E8&#39;; ">
                <a id="HeaderInclude_CashdeskSearchLink_Link" class="MainMenu" href="Default.aspx">поиск</a>
            </td>
        <td width="65" align="center" class="mainMenu" onmouseover=" this.style.background = &#39;#F5F6AF&#39;; " onmouseout=" this.style.background = &#39;#E8E8E8&#39;; ">
                <a id="HeaderInclude_SecureLink1_Link" class="MainMenu" href="Default_New.aspx">новый поиск</a>
            </td>
        <td width="65" align="center" class="mainMenu" onmouseover=" this.style.background = &#39;#F5F6AF&#39;; " onmouseout=" this.style.background = &#39;#E8E8E8&#39;; ">
                <a id="HeaderInclude_CashdeskOrders_Link" class="MainMenu" href="Admin/Admin_OrderList.aspx">заказы</a>
            </td>
        <td width="65" align="center" class="mainMenu" onmouseover=" this.style.background = &#39;#F5F6AF&#39;; " onmouseout=" this.style.background = &#39;#E8E8E8&#39;; ">
                <a id="HeaderInclude_CashdeskOrder_Link" class="MainMenu" href="Admin/Admin_Order.aspx">заказ</a>
            </td>
        <td width="65" align="center" class="mainMenu" onmouseover=" this.style.background = &#39;#F5F6AF&#39;; " onmouseout=" this.style.background = &#39;#E8E8E8&#39;; ">
                <a id="HeaderInclude_CashdeskReport_Link" class="MainMenu" href="Admin/Admin_Report.aspx">отчет</a>
            </td>
        <td width="65" align="center" class="mainMenu" onmouseover=" this.style.background = &#39;#F5F6AF&#39;; " onmouseout=" this.style.background = &#39;#E8E8E8&#39;; ">
                <a id="HeaderInclude_exit" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;HeaderInclude$exit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">выход</a>
            </td>
        <td width="250" align="center"><span id="HeaderInclude_lblCashierDeposit" class="m"></span></td>
        <td align="right"><b style="color: green;"><span id="HeaderInclude_CashierNameLabel" class="m">Кассир: tesicg</span></b></td>
        <td align="right"><img src="img/r.gif" width="6" height="28"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <!--<table border="1" bordercolor="red">
            <tr><td>Внимание! Необходимо обновить программу билетопечати до 07.12.2008. После указанного срока не обновленные программы билетопечати будут отключены.<br />
                    Для обновления программы обратитесь к вашему техническому специалисту. <br />
                    Если у вас нет техничкского специалиста:<br />
                    1. скачайте файл <a href="http://www.concert.ru/tp/TicketPrint 2.0.11.zip"><u>http://www.concert.ru/tp/TicketPrint 2.0.11.zip</u></a><br />
                    2. обратитесь к специалисту Concert.ru по тел.: +7 (903) 249-85-46<br />
                    <br /></td></tr>
        </table>-->


        <!--<h2 style="padding-left: 10px;">Поиск мероприятий</h2>-->
        <div>
            <div ng-view class="container-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I don't understand what's the connection between user control that works as menu bar and AngularJS view below. All other options in menu bar works fine.

Comment: Do you have this button inside ng-view?

Comment: No. The "exit" but is not inside ng-view.

Comment: You can try to debug the __doPostBack function? You will find it on the rendered page, it is used by asp.net to perform postback.

Comment: There is this call:

javascript:__doPostBack('HeaderInclude$exit','')

But, where can I find it?

Comment: it should be on the page (in the browser) placed inside inline <script></script> tags.

Comment: This is url od the page where AngularJS view is:

http://aaaa.bbbb.local/Default_New.aspx#/list

But, when I'm looking in "Script" section on that page I can't see __doPostBack function.

Comment: You should look for it inside of a body tag.

Comment: It's not there. Please, take a look at update in main post how the HTML page looks like.

Comment: this the code from visual studio could you post how does it look like in the browser?

Comment: It's up there under 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your page content into a form tag with runat="server" attribute:

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#333333" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%--<site:secureChecker ID="CheckRights" runat="Server" Allow="wizard,admin,buhgalter" />--%>
        <site:header id="HeaderInclude" runat="server"/>

        <!--<h2 style="padding-left: 10px;">Поиск мероприятий</h2>-->
        <div>
            <div ng-view class="container-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
    </form>
</body>
```